# Merge two commits in remote repository

Tags: git, commit

Repository of one rather small project occupies >200 megabytes. Here is how the history looks like:

```
...
1) regular commit
2) regular commit
3) commit which adds 100mb of useless files + does something useful
4) regular commit
5) commit which removes all of the useless files
6) regular commit
...
```

I want to reduce the size of the repository. Also the useful changes of commit `3` shouldn't be lost. Is there a way to combine commits `3` and `5` into one in the remote repository?

Comment: `git help rebase`, search for `interactive rebase`, and `squash`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use interactive rebase with the command:

```
git rebase -i
```

and write a rebase plan similar to this:

- pick commit 1
- pick commit 2
- pick commit 3
- **squash commit 5**
- pick commit 4
- pick commit 6
- ....

After the sucessfull rebase you can force-push the modified branch:

```
git push -f
```

**Be aware that rewriting a part of the history that has already been pushed may force other users to perform a rebase on the new history and to deal with the possible conflicts.**